# Vue $emit fires but parent component method does not trigger

Tags: vue.js

I've been trying to pass data from child to parent. I'm not quite sure why what I've got right now isn't working. I should mention that the emitter gets fired but the method in the parent component doesn't seem to get called.

Children.vue:

```
<div @click="removeCommercials()" class="">
  <u-button icon color="transparent">
    <u-icon icon="switch-on" color="white"/>
  </u-button>
</div>

methods: {
    removeCommercials () {
      this.$emit('test',{message:'HELLOOOO???'})
      console.log("AAA")
    }
  },
```

Parent.vue:

```
<Children class="mt-4" @test="noCommercials"/>

methods: {
    noCommercials(deactivate) {
      console.log("?????")
      this.deactivateCommercials = deactivate.message
      console.log("REMOVEING COMMERCIALS")
      console.log(this.deactivateCommercials)
    },
  },
```

From the console I can see the text `AAA`. From the vue developer tools I can also see the emitter getting fired with the correct data. But the method `noCommercials` in the parent component doesn't seem to trigger. Nothing from the method gets printed in the console.

From some other posts I've seen people talking about using `this.$parent.$emit` instead of `this.$emit` but that didn't do the trick for me. I've also seen others having the same problem but that's because they used the wrong child component.

I'm really confused as to why the `noCommercials` method does not trigger at all in the parent component. What am I doing wrong?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

I tried to trigger the same method from a different child component with `$emit` and it works. Now I just need to figure out why this particular child component is giving me issues.

Comment: Do you use Vue version 3? Then you have to declare your emitted events, in contrast to earlier versions, see https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#defining-custom-events

Comment: I'm on version 2.6.12

Comment: Would  you check this codepen solution  https://codepen.io/maronkoders/pen/JjELbgN?editors=1011

Comment: Your codepen solution works in codepen but I can't use that format since that's not how the project is formatted. The bigger issue is, I tried to emit from a different child component and the method gets triggered. I think the root issue is in the child component somewhere.

Comment: might not be it, but what if the click event was moved to the <u-button> ? Seems weird to see it on a div element.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried and the method doesn't get triggered either

Comment: Did you import the child component correctly?

Comment: Could you provide more information/code because I've tried using your code and it worked, the noCommercials method triggered and console logging normally. The problem might be somewhere in the parent component.